# getting object's attribute in view from request

Tags: java, struts, struts-1

Is there a way to set an attribute on my DispathAction like this:

```
request.setAttribute("myObject", object);
```

And then on my jsp get the object's attributes?

```
<%=request.getAttribute("object.attr1") %>
<%=request.getAttribute("object.attr2") %>
```

My page is not a form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Simply forget about scriptlets and learn to use the [JSP EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) and the [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info):

```
<c:out value="${myObject.attr1}"/>
<c:out value="${myObject.attr2}"/>
```

Note that this assumes the object respects JavaBean conventions, and will call `getAttr1()` and `getAttr2()` on your object. The JSTL `<c:out>` tag escapes the HTML special characters (`<`, `>`, `&`, etc.).

Comment: Thanks, Worked flawlessly for me!